# key => value pair using variables

Tags: php

So I have an array called $items, that I iterate unto:

```
foreach($area as $item) {
    $options["{$item['id']}"] = "{$item['name']} ({$item['id']})"; //pass
}
```

Each pass in the loop produces something like this:

```
[1] => string(18) "grand ballroom (1)"
```

But what I need is for it to be:

```
['1']=> string(18) "grand ballroom (1)"
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: And the difference is?

Comment: The key quote: 'If a key is the standard representation of an integer, it will be interpreted as such'. `"1"` _is_ the standard representation of an integer `1`, don't you think? )

Comment: because otherwise, I get a "Array to string conversion" error

Comment: You are trying to monkey patch your code. Please stop! Fix the actual issue instead of dicking around with other "solutions".

Comment: XY problem here. Show the code that gives you this error instead.